# How can i use sudo for freeipa user in ubuntu?

Tags: sudo, ldap, sssd

I have installed Freeipa client on Ubuntu, I am able to login using remote user credentials. But the challenge is that I'm not able to run `sudo` with the remote user.

I have tried editing the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file. But I'm still getting error.

Below is the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file. I have added `ldap` value for the `sudoers` key.

```
passwd:         compat systemd sss
group:          compat systemd sss
shadow:         compat sss
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files sss
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis sss
sudoers: files ldap
```

Comment: Let us know that what you have edited and what the error is...

Comment: Ensure that the "remote" user is a member of the `sudo` or `admin` group.

Comment: How can i add certain remote users in multiple PC's as sudo member? Is there any centralized way?